# Al ejecutar una función a través de un botón que escribe en el HTML se recarga la página y no se mantiene el texto

Tags: javascript, html, web

He creado un pequeño programa para que seleccionando una figura e introduciendo los datos pueda calcular el área. Pero al ejecutar la función que escribe sobre el HTML con .innerHtml aparece durante un momento el resultado y se va. Pasa lo mismo con la selección de la figura, ya que quiero que desaparezcan los campos que no son necesarios para calcular su área.

```js
const pi = 3.14;



var resultado;

function area_cuadrado(l){
 resultado=l*l;
 var mostrarResultado = document.getElementById("mostrarResultado");
 mostrarResultado.innerHTML="El área del cuadradp es de"+resultado+" m <sup>2</sup>";
}
function area_rectangulo(b,h){
 resultado=b*h;
 var mostrarResultado = document.getElementById("mostrarResultado");
 mostrarResultado.innerHTML="El área del rectángulo es de"+resultado+" m <sup>2</sup>";
}
function area_circulo(r){  
 resultado=pi*(r**r);
 var mostrarResultado = document.getElementById("mostrarResultado");
 mostrarResultado.innerHTML="El área del círculo es de"+resultado+" m <sup>2</sup>";
}



function seleccionarFigura(){

  var figura=document.getElementById("figura").value;
 //Campos como objetos
 var LADO=document.getElementById("lado");
  var BASE=document.getElementById("base");
  var ALTURA=document.getElementById("altura");
  var RADIO=document.getElementById("radio");
 
 switch(figura){
  case "cuadrado":
   BASE.style.display="none";
   ALTURA.style.display="none";
   RADIO.style.display="none";
   break;
   
  case "rectangulo":
   RADIO.style.display="none";
   LADO.style.display="none";
   break;
   
  case "circulo":
   BASE.style.display="none";
   ALTURA.style.display="none";
   LADO.style.display="none";
   break;
 }

}


function obtenerDatos(){
 //Recoger datos introducidos en los campos
  var lado=parseInt(document.getElementById("lado").value);
  var base=parseFloat(document.getElementById("base").value);
  var altura=parseFloat(document.getElementById("altura").value);
  var radio=parseFloat(document.getElementById("radio").value);
  var figura=document.getElementById("figura").value;

 //Determinar el caso y resolver operación
 switch(figura){
  case "cuadrado":
   area_cuadrado(lado); 
  break;
   
  case "rectangulo":
   area_rectangulo(base, altura); 
  break; 
  case "circulo":
   area_circulo(lado);  
  break;
 } 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>CALCULADOR DE ÁREAS</title>
 <meta name="title" content="Calculador de áreas">
 <meta name="description" content="Calculadoras de áreas">
 <script src="js/code.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="formulario" id="formulario">
 <fieldset>
  <h1>Calculador de áreas</h1>
  
  <label for="Figura">Figura:</label>
  <select name="figura" id="figura">
   <option value="" disabled selected>Seleccione una figura...</option>
   <option value="cuadrado">Cuadrado</option>
   <option value="rectangulo">Rectángulo</option>
   <option value="circulo">Círculo</option>
  </select>
  <button onclick="seleccionarFigura()">Establecer</button>
  <br><br>
 
 <fieldset>
  <legend>Datos</legend> 
   <label for="lado">Lado:</label>
   <input id="lado" name="lado" placeholder="Introduzca el lado" type="text">
   <label for="base">Base:</label>
   <input id="base" name="base" placeholder="Introduzca la base" type="text">
   <label for="altura">Altura:</label>
   <input id="altura" name=altura" placeholder="Introduzca la altura" type="text">
   <label for="radio">Radio:</label>
   <input id="radio" name="radio" placeholder="Introduzca el radio" type="text">
 </fieldset>
  
  <br><br>
   <button type="submit" id="boton" onclick="obtenerDatos()">Resultado</button>
  <br><br>

 <fieldset>
  <legend>Resultado</legend> 
  <p id="mostrarResultado"></p>
 </fieldset>

 </fieldset>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tus botones están realizando el "submit" cuando los presionas. Controla este comportamiento agregando a ambos la propiedad `type="button"`.

Cambia:
`<button onclick="seleccionarFigura()">Establecer</button>`

por:
`<button type="button" onclick="seleccionarFigura()">Establecer</button>`

También cambia `<button type="submit" id="boton" onclick="obtenerDatos()">Resultado</button>`

por:
`<button type="button" id="boton" onclick="obtenerDatos()">Resultado</button>`

Y te sugiero que antes del `switch(figura)` de `seleccionarFigura()`, definas la propiedad `display` de todos los elementos, para volverlos visibles:

`LADO.style.display="inline-block";`

`BASE.style.display="inline-block";`

`ALTURA.style.display="inline-block";`

`RADIO.style.display="inline-block";`

Comment: sería mejor no solo para el OP si no para el resto de la comunidad que argumentes el por que de lo que recomiendas hacer

Comment: Otra opción para evitar que se refresque la página es usar `event.preventDefault()` dentro de `obtenerDatos(event)`

Comment: Para utilizar `event.preventDefault()` tendrá que agregar el parametro `event` en la función, y enviar los objetos y eventos en `onclick()` de ambos `button`.

Comment: Ya funciona correctamente, muchas gracias.